# Magento 2 Escrow Payment Integration

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway

How can I integrate the escrow payment gateway in my custom payment method in Magento 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Vendor/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <Modulenamepayment>
                <model>Vendor\Modulename\Model\PaymentMethod</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Modulename Payment</title>
                <order_status>pending_payment</order_status><!-- set default order status-->
            </Modulenamepayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Modulename/Model/PaymentMethod.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model;

/**
 * Pay In Store payment method model
 */
class PaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    /**
     * Payment code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'Modulenamepayment';
}
```

> Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="Modulenamepayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="Modulenamepayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method-action.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
        'mage/url',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
    ],
    function ($, quote, urlBuilder, url, storage, errorProcessor, customer, fullScreenLoader) {
        'use strict';
        return function (messageContainer) {
            window.location.href = window.checkoutConfig.redirect_url;
        };
    }
);
```

> Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/Modulenamepayment.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Vendor_Modulename/js/action/set-payment-method-action'
    ],
    function (Component,setPaymentMethodAction) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                redirectAfterPlaceOrder : false,
                template: 'Vendor_Modulename/payment/Modulenamepayment'
            },
            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'Modulenamepayment',
                component: 'Vendor_Modulename/js/view/payment/method-renderer/Modulenamepayment'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

> Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/template/payment-method/Modulenamepayment.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Vendor/Modulename/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Vendor\Modulename\Model\ModulenamePaymentFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $checkoutSession;

    protected $customerFactory;

    protected $resultRedirect;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
        ModulenamePaymentFactory $ModulenamePayment,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_ModulenamePayment = $ModulenamePayment;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $incrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
        $this->redirectToPaymentGateWay($incrementId);
    }

    /**
    *  Redirect to Payemnt Page 
    **/
    public function redirectToPaymentGateWay($incrementId){
        $baseUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $returnUrl = $baseUrl.'checkout\onepage\success';
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        $getorderdata = $orderData->getData();
        $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
        $itemData = array();
        $productId = $seller_email = $itemQty = $itemDesc = $itemName = $itemPrice = '';
        $buyer_email = $orderData->getCustomerEmail();
        $vendor_commission_total = 20;
        $order_name = $incrementId;
        foreach($orderItems as $orderItems){
            $productId = $orderItems->getProductId();
            $product_collection_marketplace = $objectManager->create('Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Product')->load($productId,'mageproduct_id');
            $sellerId = $product_collection_marketplace->getSellerId();
            $seller = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($sellerId);
            $seller_email = $seller->getEmail();
            $itemQty = $orderItems->getQtyOrdered();
            $itemDesc = $orderItems->getDescription();
            $itemName = $orderItems->getName();
            $itemPrice = $orderItems->getRowTotal();
        }
        $address = $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();

        $stateName = $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();

        $regionArray = $this->getRegionCode($stateName);

        /* New Code Satrt */
        $request_array = array();

        $request_array["currency"]="usd";

        $request_array["items"][0]["description"]= $itemName;

        $request_array["items"][0]["fees"][0]=array(
            "payer_customer" => "me",
            "split" => "1",
            "type" => "Modulename"
        );

        $request_array["items"][0]["inspection_period"]="259200";

        $request_array["items"][0]["quantity"]= floatval($itemQty);


        $request_array["items"][0]["schedule"][0]=array(
                "payer_customer"=>$buyer_email,
                "amount"=>$itemPrice,
                "beneficiary_customer"=>"me"
        );

        $request_array["items"][0]["title"] = $itemName;


        $request_array["items"][0]["type"] = "general_merchandise";

        $request_array["items"][1]["type"] = "shipping_fee";

        $request_array["items"][1]["schedule"][0]=array(
            "payer_customer"=>$buyer_email,
            "amount"=>$orderData->getShippingAmount(),
            "beneficiary_customer"=>"me"
        );

        $request_array["description"] = $itemName;

        $request_array["parties"][0]=array(
            "agreed"=>"1",
            "customer"=>$buyer_email,
            "role"=>"buyer",
            "first_name"=>$orderData->getCustomerFirstname(),
            "last_name"=>$orderData->getCustomerLastname(),
            "phone_number"=>$orderData->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone()
        );

        $request_array["parties"][0]["address"]=array(
            "line1"=> "address",
            "line2" => "address",
            "city" => $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
            "state" => $regionArray['region_id'],
            "country" => $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId(),
            "post_code" => $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()
        );


        $request_array["parties"][1]=array(
            "agreed" => "true",
            "customer" => "me",
            "initiator" => "true",
            "role" =>"seller"
        );


        $request_array["return_url"] = $returnUrl;

        /* New Code End */

        $Modulename_email = Your Modulename account email id

        $Modulename_api_key = Your Modulename account Api Key

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.Modulename-sandbox.com/integration/pay/2018-03-31",
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => $Modulename_email . ':' . $Modulename_api_key,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($request_array)
        ));

        // Make the call to the Modulename.com API.
        $output = curl_exec($curl);

        // Get the HTTP status of the response.
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        // Close the curl command as we are done using it.
        curl_close($curl);


        $redirecturl= null;

        $response = $array = json_decode($output);

        $newdt = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

        if(isset($newdt['landing_page']) && isset($newdt['transaction_id'])) {
           $redirecturl=$newdt['landing_page'];
            ?>
            <script>
                //document.getElementById("benifits-formsubmit").submit();
                window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirecturl; ?>";
            </script>
            <?php 
        }else{
            echo "error";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $region
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRegionCode(string $region): array
    {
        $regionCode = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addRegionNameFilter($region)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->toArray();
        return $regionCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works for me. Happy coding!